# Narrowing down a broad question about a language's performance/security

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, needs-more-focus

Earlier I asked a question on SO about [trying to figure out if there were any security/performance issues with backporting code from Java 1.8 to 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29853080/are-there-security-performance-issues-with-backporting-java-code-from-1-8-to-1-5). My reasoning behind asking the question was because I plan to backport some of my 1.8 code for someone to use in their 1.5 application, but I'm unsure of whether or not there are any significant downsides to doing so. This was closed as being too broad and I can understand the reasoning behind that since it is a broad subject. However, I'm not sure about how to edit my question to narrow down my question further.

Would it be better to ask something like this on a different SE site? Or would it be better to ask it on a non-SE site like a forum? Or is there someway to still salvage my question?

Comment: I don't think it's salvageable, too much of a "tell me your war stories" question. Not a bad question, just not one that fits the strict confines of the Q&A philosophy of the site. Have you tried asking in chat? Chat is much more relaxed than the main site, and often those overly broad questions can be excellent conversation starters.

Comment: @Yannis I haven't really tried out the chat but you're right, it sounds like it would be better suited as a chat discussion rather than Q&A.